# Accessing dynamic links in the format of domain.com/<dynamic_page_name> in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller, codeigniter-2

I am using code Igniter for my PHP project. I want to give provision in my site such that users can create new pages of their own, and access them directly from **domain.com/their_page_name**.

But, my developers have raised a concern that, 1000's of dynamic links that are presented in the format of domain.com/ is "not good for site's performance". For some 10-15 pages, it is fine. But, beyond that, it would effect the site's performance.

So, they proposed that the URL format should be like **www.domain.com/something/page_name** (here, 'something' is the controller name, as they mentioned it)

But, I really can't sacrifice my framework nor my requirement.

Is there any way that I can achieve the format of "**www.domain.com/page_name**" without effecting the site's performance?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can have uri segment like `$id` that would help to search pages easier. Many of popular portals use that concept. For example `domain.com/32767/page_unique_name` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

No issues on 
Www.domain.com\userpagename.

It's not a framework issues. Codeigniter support this type of URL.you can create n no of URL.
Performance will matter how you are handling that particular controller or that particular function.
If may be 10 may be 100 ,work around same way.

You just have to put route accordingly.

$route[`default_controller`]=`userurl`;
$route[`userurl`/(:any)`]=`userurl yourfunction/$1`;

Comment: Thanks a lot sayak..just one doubt...with this routing, can i access a page from  domain.com/sayak  such that my final landing URL would be the same (domain.com/sayak) ?

Answer (score 0):

What it seems you need is dynamic controller, which can be done using Codeigniter's build in function _remap().

A code example is:

```
public function _remap($method){
     if($method != null){
          $this->yourFunction($method);
     } else {
          // handle the error as you like
     }
}

public function yourFunction($key){
      // your code logic here
}
```

All this code block goes inside your controller.

Edit: the performance is exactlu the same as going with domain.com/controller/method. What it matters, as stated above, is how you handle the data.